# MYSQL TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE give me this error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

#### after update user I get this error

> `ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

#### And this is my trigger, I want to remove user when his fame under 0

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_fame AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  IF NEW.fame < 0 THEN
    DELETE FROM users WHERE login = OLD.login;
  END IF;
END
```

**What is the error ?**

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would help.  That said, the error message seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `fame` to always be positive, then use a `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT chk_users_fame CHECK (fame >= 0);
```

A trigger is not needed for this operation in the more recent versions of MySQL.

In older versions you can use a trigger but you want to prevent the `update`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_fame BEFORE UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.fame < 0 THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fame must never be negative';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: No I do not want to keep fame > 0, but I want to remove the user who his fame become < 0

Comment: @bad-ass_1337 . . . Just use a view to select the rows where the fame is non-negative.